Browning leaves on a cherry sapling
After years of failed attempts, I recently harvested a small cherry sapling about 6 1/2 inches tall for soil line to top) from a tree my grandfather planted as a young man. It is very important to me as he passed away many years ago and the tree was something that took great pride and enjoyment in.
I placed it in a terra cotta pot and used miracle grow potting soil when I potted it. It has been in the pot for 18 days. The pot is kept outside on my back porch that is covered but not enclosed. The sapling gets most of its sunlight in the am to mid afternoon. I water it a little bit everyday or two. The soil feels moist but not wet.
A couple days ago I noticed a pale brown patch forming on the lowest of the three leaves and a bit around the edges. Now I am also seeing a bit of pale browning on the edges of the other two leaves. The leaves seem a bit paler in color and the top leaf has a bit of curling at the edges.
Any advice on what the problem is and how I can possibly solve it... I've been trying for years to get a sapling from his tree. The original tree is sickly and will soon need to be removed so I really don't want to loose this sapling as it may be my last chance to carry on the legacy. Also, if anyone could grant a guess as to the type of cherry tree this is I would be very grateful. It is a sweet cherry.
Pictures of the sapling




Pictures of the parent tree



Hi @Jennifer, and welcome to the site.  That's a beautiful way to remember your grandfather.  A real Family Tree :-)

Was the cherry tree ever cutted? Maybe it is the point of view in the picture, but it looks really large. Cherries, if bred for fruits, need cutting each or each second year to keep them healthy. In general cherry trees cope this good, even if you cut them  nearly "naked". If you think about removing it, you maybe want to try this first. In worsed case you remove it as planned, in best case it gets well again.

For your small tree it could be a try, to take some soil from the old cherry tree (not only from the top where the grass grows, but also from deeper level, where the roots are). It could infuse the small roots with micro organisms helpful for it. Trees shape their surrounding to fit them as best as possible because they can not move.
